# What should I use for $f(\zeta)$ to test for the solution to Laplace's Equation obtained using Green's Function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, greens-function

I'm trying to compute the solution obtained via Green's Function to test it. It's for Laplace's equation for a semi-infinite slab defined for $y>0$. Here is a snippet from the [document which I have been following along](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Introduction_to_Partial_Differential_Equations_(Herman)/07%3A_Green%27s_Functions/7.05%3A_Greens_Functions_for_the_2D_Poisson_Equation) below showing the problem and it's solution:

[image]

I tried a couple different solutions which satisfy Laplace's Equation and plugged in for $f(\zeta)$ but they didn't work, so I'm assuming that I need to test a specific function to satisfy this problem. What should I plug in to test for this problem?

Thus far I've tried $u(x,y) = y^2 - x^2$. I tried this on the finite domain $x\in [-5,5], y\in [0,10]$ and I plugged in for $f(x,0) = f(x) = -x^2$ and I tried to get the solution for the point (0.1,0.1) to get:

$$u(0.1,0.1) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-5}^5 \frac{0.1}{(0.1-\zeta)^2+0.1^2}\zeta^2d\zeta$$ and plugging this into wolframalpha to obtain a solution, I get 0.318. I was expecting $u(x,y) = 0.1^2 - 0.1^2 = 0$.

EDIT: Modifying the integral to be on an infinite domain, we instead have:

$$u(0.1,0.1) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{0.1}{(0.1-\zeta)^2+0.1^2}\zeta^2d\zeta$$
And this integral does not converge.

Finding the indefinite integral we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int\frac{y}{(x-\zeta)^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{4\pi}y(x\ln(x^2-2x\zeta+2\zeta^2)+2\zeta)$$. Plugging this into the expression F(b) - F(a) where F is the antiderivative, we get:
$$u(0.1,0.1)=\frac{1}{4\pi}(\lim_{\zeta\rightarrow\infty}.2\zeta+.01\ln(.1^2-.2\zeta+2\zeta^2)-\lim_{\zeta\rightarrow-\infty}.2\zeta+.01\ln(.1^2-.2\zeta+2\zeta^2)) = \frac{1}{4\pi}((\infty + \infty)-(-\infty-\infty)) = \infty$$
Which means the integral does not converge.

So the question still remains, what function $f(\zeta)$ can I plug in to obtain the solution $u(x,y)$ for this problem?

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn’t make sense. Edit to include the details of what you’ve tried.

Comment: @TedShifrin Done! Hopefully that's clear. I'm working this out in Python/Matlab and worked it out on finite intervals with spacing of $\delta{x} = 0.1$ to approximate a continuous domain. I'm assuming this is how the computation would be carried out on C instead of performing the integral over an infinite domain of integration.

Comment: You have to integrate over the entire $x$-axis to use this formula. You can’t apply it to a finite rectangle. The Green’s function depends totally on the actual region. For your example, you can do the integral by hand directly.

Comment: Your very last integral does in fact converge unless I'm missing something... it is equivalent to the arctangent derivative after some substitutions, so you get $u(0.1, 0.1) = \frac{1}{\pi} (\arctan(\infty) - \arctan(- \infty)) = 1$

Comment: @DanielGeyfman Perhaps. Make sure you plug in $f(\zeta) = \zeta^2$. I'm going to parse through it for bit. Hold on, I made a mistake in typing out the integrand

Comment: @TedShifrin So the problem now is that the integral does not converge when we integrate over the infinite domain for the function chosen for $f(\zeta) = \zeta^2$. As DanielGeyfman above has inadvertently worked out, if $f(\zeta) = 1$ and we just integrate Green's Function, then it does converge to 1, but the question then becomes does it converge to the correct value at $u(0.1,0.1)$? if the function is say $f(x,y) = 1-y^2$, then we would plug in $f(\zeta) = 1$, but the result should be 0.99. So, clearly the selection of functions for $f(x,y)$ is limited, and I don't what any are.

Comment: @DanielGeyfman I went in and checked and it should be what you found if we plugged in $f(\zeta) = 1$. For $f(\zeta) = \zeta^2$ I do not get that it converges. Also I apologize for the confusion as I wrote the integrand wrong and have since edited it.